# iPhone 6 scaling using launch images

Tags: iphone, ios8, scaling

My app scales the same on iPhone 6 and 6 plus as on the 5. I'm trying to get the app to use the extra screen space on the larger phone. I've read about using the appropriate size launch images, but it only works in the simulator, not on the device. I added a 750x1334 launch image for the iPhone 6, and the various sizes for the other devices. When I launch in the simulator, the scaling takes place as expected. When I launch on the device, the screen scales to the iPhone 4s scale instead.

I tried starting over with the launch images, and adding one at a time. Whenever I add the 750x1334 for the Retina HD 4.7, the app on the phone scales to iPhone 4 size. I tried deleting the app and reinstalling but the same thing happens. Also, I notice now that when I put in the Retina HD 4.7 image, it also causes the same thing to happen on my iPhone 5, even though there is an appropriate launch image for that size device.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDITED TO ADD: My wife's iPhone 6 Plus just came in and it does not exhibit the above behavior (but remains a problem with iPhone 6 and 5).

Comment: Are you using the assets catalog? And have you set the the appropriate reference in your projects settings? By the way, in the inspector of the Assets Catalog you are able to select and deselect certain types of launch images.

Comment: Thanks for your response, tscheepers. I am using the Assets catalog. The settings point at the relevant asset catalog.

Comment: have you tried deleting your derived data directory?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Anthony. Deleting the derived data did not help,unfortunately.

Comment: @JasonTyler The xcasset doesn't work properly with iPhone 5S if you target `iOS6`. In that case, you have to target `iOS7`. Maybe there is a similar behavior for iPhone 6/6+. Can you try to change your deployment target for `iOS7` or `iOS8` and try again ?

Comment: Hi kl94, thanks for the tip. But I am already targeting iOS7, so I'm still puzzled about what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve the desired result through doing the following:

1) leave in place my old Launch Images Source configuration set that covered iPhone 4 and 5. This takes care of iOS 7 devices.

2) create and designate a Launch Screen File in XIB. This takes care of all devices on iOS 8.

3) On iPhone 6, under Settings --> Display and Brightness --> Display Zoom, choose Standard instead of Zoomed. Users who have Zoomed will see the screen scaled to the same as that of iPhone 5.