# iPhone 6 Launch Image/Launch File issue

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-6

I added to the project the Launch images for enabling support of iPhone 6/6+ (1242×2208 & 750×1334). 
[image]

For iPhone 6+ everything works correctly, but for iPhone 6 on the real device (iOS 8.4.1), I still see Launch Image for iPhone 5 and screen size {320x568}. In the simulator of iPhone 6 app works as expected (correct launch image and screen size {375x667}).
[image]

The same behaviour if I use Launch File instead of Launch Image Assets.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The question is duplicated and the answer is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26504069/697530

iOS handles correctly the Launch Images for iPhone 6/6+. It is enough to specify Launch Image in the Assets, and do not use Launch File for iOS8, but "Display Zoom" in the Settings of the phone must be set to the "Standard" mode for iPhone6 (Settings -> Display & Brightness -> View).

Hope it will help to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below screen with Lunch image setting and you have to select one by one lunch image box and check size of image e.g. Image_2.png and set image based on that size.

Image_1.png
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdkPn.png

Image_2.png
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJdg6.png

Make sure your image size is same as the size of selected box.

Hope this is work for you.

Thanks :)